# My layout don't have the same theme

Tags: android

i have a pretty weird bug on my app, some all of my layout doesn't have the same theme, and i don't know why ! Here some image !

[image: Here my notification bar is invisible]

[image: I want This]

I want this one !

But i can't figure why i have this problem !

Here is my manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Actuality"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login_Register.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login_Register.Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Rank"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scores"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Game"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_jeux"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Games.Symptom"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_symptomes"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_compte"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Games.Hanged"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pendu"
        android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Lesson" />
</application>
```

Can someone explain me why plz :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main screen is the only with correct action bar, is because you have different theme in your app and in your layout:

```
<application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme">
```

and

```
<activity
    ....
    android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme.NoActionBar">
```

If you want black bar I would use same theme in all activities than in application:

```
<activity
    ....
    android:theme="@style/IfsiTheme">
```

Comment: Oh yeah i see ! So in the preview, when i change theme, it don't change it on the manifest ?